# Drone segment in URL cannot contain colon

Tags: drone.io

I got the below error while setting up Drone CI.

> myid:bin domain$ drone info parse
>   “http://drone5.internal.com/”/api/user: first path segment in URL
>   cannot contain colon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched online for answer but didnt get the right one.
Finally I found that it was due to the URL syntax I am getting the error.

while setting up the variables dont use double quotes.

export DRONE_SERVER="https://drone5.internal.com" is wrong.

But

export DRONE_SERVER=https://drone5.internal.com will work perfectly